# How to link to login page?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to do something a priori simple.

I wish in a template to add a link to the login page.

I found [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates), so I know how to link to a node etc. but to a url type "/ login", I did not find.

Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`link`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#link) function and the route for the login page (`user.login`), e.g.

```
{{ link('Login', 'route:user.login') }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, it's possible to have just the url ? and not the entire tag?

Comment: I think I found, is that it? '{{ path('user.login') }}'